# pyqt5 keeping image from overflowing qlabel

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have been trying to keep the image set from qpixmap to not overflow to qlabel border. The goal is to have the qlabel crop any portion of the image that does not fit into the qlabel.

**Here is the code i'm using:**

```
    self.pPic = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)  
    self.pPic.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 55, 150, 140))
    self.pPic.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid blue; border-radius: 40px;") 
    self.pPic.setScaledContents(True)
    self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    self.pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
    self.pixmap.scaled(self.pPic.width(),self.pPic.height())
    self.pixmap.loadFromData(pFile_picLink)
    self.pPic.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.pPic.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.pPic.setObjectName("PPic")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Then, there are some misconceptions here that need some clarifications:

- you can't "crop" the contents of the pixmap just like that, since the stylesheet set for the QLabel doesn't care about its contents;
- [`QPixmap.scaled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-1) returns "*a copy of the pixmap scaled to a rectangle with the given width and height*"; since you're not using its returned value, your call its completely useless;
- the call to [`fill()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fill) is not necessary if you're going to load data from an existing file, as long as that data is successfully loaded;

The only way to "crop" the image as you'd like to do is to apply *clipping* (which is the more accurate term for this kind of image processing).
Note that stylesheets applied to Qt cannot be directly accessed, so you don't have a direct way to know the `border-radius` value.

```
    source = QtGui.QPixmap()
    # I really don't know what "pFile_picLink" is, but you really shouldn't use it
    # like that; use python's "with open()" or QFile.readAll() instead.
    source.loadFromData(pFile_picLink)
    output = QtGui.QPixmap(source.width(), source.height())
    output.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

    # create a new QPainter on the output pixmap
    qp = QtGui.QPainter(output)
    clipPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    # the "40" value is taken from the border radius of the label stylesheet
    clipPath.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(source.rect()), 40, 40)
    # clip the contents to the rounded path we just created
    qp.setClipPath(clipPath)
    qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, source)
    # ending the QPainter object is mandatory when dealing with painter
    # objects created for images
    qp.end()

    self.pPic.setPixmap(output)
```

Finally, and completely unrelated, avoid mixing import styles: in your code there's a `Qt.transparent` and a `QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter`.
Use either `from PyQt5 import QtCore` along with `QtCore.Qt.whatever`, or `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` with `Qt.whatever`; mixing them is just confusing and absolutely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

what @musicamante wrote about might look like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import requests


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        url_image = 'https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49251422908_591245c64a_c_d.jpg'

        source = QtGui.QImage()
        source.loadFromData(requests.get(url_image).content)       
        self.resize(source.width(), source.height())

        output = QtGui.QPixmap(source.width(), source.height())
        output.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        qp = QtGui.QPainter(output)
        clipPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        clipPath.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(source.rect()), source.width()//2, source.width()//2)
        qp.setClipPath(clipPath)
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, QtGui.QPixmap(source))
        qp.end()

        self.pPic = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.pPic.setPixmap(output)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.pPic, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: If you are not providing an answer that is actually an alternative to the existing one, just suggest an edit for it, don't create a new one that has the same concepts, as it's completely unnecessary and is considered as noise.